# PHP: Can I define a new class instance inside of a 'parent' class and have the new instance extend the parent

Tags: php

Im wanting to do something like:

```
class foo extends bar {
  private $norf = '';
  private $script;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->norf = 'blah blah';
  }

  public function qux(){
    $this->script = new someOtherClass();
    return $this->script->displayNorf();
  }
}

class someOtherClass {
    public function displayNorf(){
        return $this->norf;
    }
}

$test = new foo();
print($test->qux()); //blah blah
```

This example is really stupid but Im looking for a way to extend the instance of a class.

Comment: If you define `someOtherClass` as extending `foo`, then yes.... it will extend the class... but not a specific instance of a class (because that's now what OOP is)..... but the logic behind why you want to be able to define arbitrary classes is unclear.... perhaps you need anonymous classes?

Comment: Honestly out of laziness. I will take the same approach but pass in the 'parent' as an argument, i just wanted to use $this instead of having to take that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create instances of other classes inside your class. However, your code sample won't work simply because the class `someOtherClass` does not contain a property named `$norf`.

`$this` refers to the current instance of the class, so in `someOtherClass->displayNorf()`, since the class does not contain a property named `$norf` you'll receive an undefined property error.

In order for this to work, you'll need to change the `foo` class's property `$norf` from `private` to `protected` and extend the `foo` class through the `someOtherClass` class like so:

```
class foo extends bar {
  protected $norf = '';
  private $script;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->norf = 'blah blah';
  }

  public function qux(){
    $this->script = new someOtherClass();
    return $this->script->displayNorf();
  }
}

class someOtherClass extends foo {
    public function displayNorf(){
        return $this->norf;
    }
}

$test = new foo();
print($test->qux()); //blah blah
```

Comment: I was hoping to keep norf private BUT I dont intend on using more than one instance of foo so this would be fine in this case. Ok cool Ill use this approach. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is yes. If you run the code below, The output will be `blah blah`.

```
<code>
<?php
class foo {
  protected $norf = '';
  private $script;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->norf = 'blah blah';
  }

  public function qux(){
    $this->script = new someOtherClass();
    return $this->script->displayNorf();
  }
}

class someOtherClass extends foo {
    public function displayNorf(){
        return $this->norf;
    }
}
$test = new foo();
print($test->qux()); //blah blah
?>
</code>
```